# What does it mean to link against a local shared library in CMake?

Tags: cmake, shared-libraries

In cmake I specify a library like this:

`add_library(vision_algs SHARED...`

Then without installing it anywhere I link against that shared library with a target like:

`target_link_libraries(something vision_algs ...`

What does this mean? I thought shared libraries live in a specific folder in the OS. If the shared library isn't installed there, how is it even linking? Are these libraries placed by Cmake in the build folder and if I move the executable will it not be able to run?

Comment: Shared libraries can recide anywhere; as long as you tell the linker about the absolute path of the lib (or import lib on windows), you can link the lib. The only potential issue is the program potentially not finding the shared library at runtime. That can be fixed by system dependent means though, see Alex's answer for some of those...

Answer (score 1):

> I thought shared libraries live in a specific folder in the OS.

This is not true in any of the major operating systems I'm aware of. Certainly not Windows, Linux, macOS, or BSD.

UNIX-y systems have an executable property called "RPATH" that extends (supersedes) the system search path for libraries. CMake sets the RPATH of the executables it builds to point directly at the shared libraries it also built. Because CMake uses absolute paths, executables in the build tree are unsuitable for deployment. This is fixed at installation time, when CMake replaces the RPATH it set with the value of the `INSTALL_RPATH` target property on a per-executable basis. This property is initialized by `CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH`, which is empty by default. It is customary to set this to something like `$ORIGIN:$ORIGIN/../lib` on Linux or `@loader_path:@loader_path/../lib` on macOS.

Windows, on the other hand does not have RPATH. Instead, it looks for libraries in the same directory as the executable and then searches the `PATH` environment variable. It is customary to set `CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` such that libraries and executables are all staged in the same folder at build time. It is also common to add build paths to the `PATH` environment variable while running tests, if one does not wish to alter the build tree layout.

Comment: What do you mean by "system search path" this is the path(s) where shared libaries live right? What does the default RPATH point to? Basically I just want to know where the shared library goes if it isn't "installed" in the OS, and how the unix executeable finds it?

Comment: The "loader" on Unix-y systems is responsible for loading libraries, and looks through the RPATH first. The default RPATH is empty, so the search continues with the system path. Thus, the shared library can live in any folder. CMake generally puts things in a folder corresponding to the source tree layout, but you have a lot of control over this (e.g. via `CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`).